# OS X is messing with me css, how to fix

Tags: css, macos, forms

So I made a form and added styling with CSS, it looks fine on windows but when I go to the form with my Mac it looks diffrent, everything is smaller and has changed color.
Why is OS X changing my CSS?
And is there a way to fix this problem?

Image of problem: http://i.tinyuploads.com/zq3rtp.png

This problem happens in every browser on my Mac

HTML Code:

```
<p>Name:<span class="Req-ourForm">*</span></p> <input type="text" required="required" name="name">
<br /><br />
<p>Email:<span class="Req-ourForm">*</span></p> <input type="text" required="required" name="email">
<br /><br />
<p>Website:<span class="Req-ourForm">*</span></p> <input type="text" required="required" name="website">
<br /><br />

<p>Priority:<span class="Req-ourForm">*</span></p>
<!--[if !IE]> --> <div class="notIE"> <!-- <![endif]-->
<label />
<select class="pri" name="priority" size="1" required="required">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
</select>
<!--[if !IE]> --></div> <!-- <![endif]-->
<br />
```

CSS Code:

```
input, textarea { 
    padding: 9px;
    border: solid 1px #C9C9C9; 
    outline: 0;
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    width: 200px;
    background: #e2e2e2 url('bg_form.png') left top repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    }

input.sub { 
    padding: 9px;
    border: solid 1px #C9C9C9; 
    outline: 0;
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    width: 300px;
    background: #e2e2e2 url('bg_form.png') left top repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    }

input.captcha { 
    padding: 9px;
    border: solid 1px #C9C9C9; 
    outline: 0;
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    width: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #e2e2e2 url('bg_form.png') left top repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    }

textarea {
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 380px;
    max-width: 380px;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150%;
    }

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus { 
    border-color: #b3b3b3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px;
    @include box-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1));
    border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
    }

.form label { 
    margin-left: 10px;  
    color: #999999; 
    }

.submit input {
    width: auto;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    background: #617798;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #C9C9C9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }


/*CSS FOR DROP DOWN*/
label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
select {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px 5px 5px;
    width: 160px;
    outline: none;
    color: #74646e;
    border: 1px solid #C8BFC4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd8dc;
    background-color: #fff;        
}
select.pri {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px 5px 5px;
    width: 85px;
    outline: none;
    color: #74646e;
    border: 1px solid #C8BFC4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd8dc;
    background-color: #fff;        
}
select.aop {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px 5px 5px;
    width: 60px;
    outline: none;
    color: #74646e;
    border: 1px solid #C8BFC4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd8dc;
    background-color: #fff;        
}
select.stu {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px 5px 5px;
    width: 65px;
    outline: none;
    color: #74646e;
    border: 1px solid #C8BFC4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd8dc;
    background-color: #fff;        
}
```

Second issue is that the buttons are for some reason white instead of blue,
IMG: http://i.tinyuploads.com/pW0E24.png

HTML code of buttons:

```
<button id="continue-link" class="button button rect" type="submit"> 
<span>
    <span class="effect"></span>
    <span class="label"> 
        SEND    
    </span>
</span>
</button>


<button id="continue-link" class="button button rect" type="reset"> 
<span>
    <span class="effect"></span>
    <span class="label"> 
        CLEAR ALL    
    </span>
</span>
</button>
```

CSS of buttons:

```
/*BUTTON DESIGN*/
.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    border-collapse: separate;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 11px/1.5 "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
.button > span {
    background: url("common/src/store/base/patterns/buttons/css/bg/button_colors.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 / 8px 22px #224272;
    border: 1px solid #224272;
    border-radius: 11px 11px 11px 11px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 12px/1 "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 4px 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: 0;
}
.button:-moz-focusring {
    outline: 0px dotted;
}
.ns .button, .button.rect {
    background: linear-gradient(#37AAEA, #117ED2) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #1992D9;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; /*BUTTON ROUNDNESS*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}
.ns .button:hover, .ns .button:focus, .button.rect:hover, .button.rect:focus {
    background: linear-gradient(#2F90D5, #0351B7) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.ns .button:active, .ns .button.active, .button.rect:active, .button.rect.active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF, 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
.ns .button > span, .button.rect > span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 4px 20px; /*BUTTON SIZE*/
}
```

Comment: please show your code and the browsers that you're using

Comment: @shinnyx I added the code and what browser it happens in

Comment: Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none` to the input,textarea ruleset.

Comment: Styling select elements has always been inconsistant between browsers. A decent reset solution like normalize.css. Link to git hub http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: OS X isn’t changing your CSS. With regards to the font colour (I think the letters are actually the same height, having zoomed in and compared), different operating systems render fonts differently. (And the same operating system can render fonts differently with different settings — e.g. ClearType in Windows.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite its not the fonts that are wrong its the Select box

Comment: @MauritzN: ah, I see. In that case, “everything is smaller and has changed color” wasn’t the best choice of words.

Comment: @Vector that worked, but that did not fix the problem that I am having with the buttons, IMG: http://i.tinyuploads.com/8MoAbh.png, The white boxes are suppose to be light blue. This is how it's suppose to be: http://i.tinyuploads.com/t44WhG.png

Comment: The issue with the blue buttons will be something simple and easy. Have you got a link to the site, i'll have a quick look using google dev tools

Comment: @Vector the site is https://heroknights.net/webdesign

Comment: @MauritzN I just posted an answer that should clear things up. Always ensure you use browser prefix where required for complete cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @Vector yes I saw the answer, but there is a problem with it, its not the same gradient that I had, how it is suppose to look: http://i.tinyuploads.com/pW0E24.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your button is not blue is because you are not declaring a webkit gradient. I had a look at your stylesheet. Add the correct prefix for various browsers as below -

```
.ns .button, .button.rect {
background: linear-gradient(#37AAEA, #117ED2) repeat scroll 0 0;
background: linear-gradient(#37AAEA, #117ED2) repeat scroll 0 0;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#37AAEA, #117ED2) repeat scroll 0 0;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#37AAEA, #117ED2) repeat scroll 0 0;
background:  -o-llinear-gradient(#37AAEA, #117ED2) repeat scroll 0 0;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border: 1px solid #1992D9;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; /*BUTTON ROUNDNESS*/
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

This ensures your gradient will work on all browsers that support it.

Comment: yes uhmmm, that seems to work, but the gradient looks really weird, it's not the same as it use to be.

Comment: I've updated it. I used it as an example to show you, you could update it with your colours. I've now updated it with your colours for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great and works great, well except for one thing, the hover effect it not working on OS X. I would be grateful if you could try to fix that or find the problem

Comment: Never mind, I added all the gradient things to that as well, now it works perfectly :D, thanks

Comment: Hey if it would not be to much to ask, would I be able to keep in contact with you? So if I have a problem again I could contact you? and you would try to fix it?

Comment: Glad to help. If you post your problems here on stackoverflow I will probably see them as I check on here a couple of times a day, most days.